# Use chebyshev inequality to find the probability $P[|X-E[X]| \ge k\sigma]$

Tags: probability, inequality, standard-deviation

￼[image]

> For an arbitrary random variable $X$, use the [Chebyshev inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_inequality) to show that the probability that $X$ is more than $k$ standard deviations from its expected value $E[X]$ satisfies
>   $$P[|X-E[X]| \ge k\sigma] \le \frac1{k^2}$$

Hi every one,
I found this problem in the book 
any idea?

Answer (score 4):

When you use Chebyshev's inequality, you get that
$$ P\left( \lvert X - \mathbb{E}X \rvert \geq k \sigma \right) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E} \lvert X - \mathbb{E}X \rvert^2}{k^2 \sigma^2}.$$
What is the quantity in the numerator?